# How to prevent a selected TextField to be cleared when we put the app in the background?

Tags: flutter, textfield

Is there a way to prevent a selected `TextField` to be cleared when we lock the phone or put the app in the background? 
The content of a `TextField` is saved in this case if it is not selected.

Thanks!

Comment: I have this problem too... In my case, just with Android.. Sometimes it seems that the OS close de app or can't keep the state... It just occur with older devices, with low memory available..

Comment: @siega I have a Huawei p20 and a Motorola g6, same behavior on both

Comment: I've found this open issue on Github : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51947